# Storing time in database

Tags: android

I'm wondering which is the best way to store a time into a database.
Is it better to store the time in millis as a LONG value or use the sql DATE type.

I want to store a time into the SQLite database of the android device and send it later to a server. Which is the best way in consideration of performance.

Comment: depends on your use case. ie what type of `Date` is the server you wanna send the data to expecting? Do You need Date related queries inside SQL?

Comment: Personally I prefer storing all time values as milliseconds (Long)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered both methods and both are valid options. Personally I would go with the sql DATE method since you have many predefined methods with reading/manipulating/writing dates in SQLite, as explained [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Storing time in millis is fine if you're willing to run extra calculations to verify the accuracy of the data later on, coming from a QA perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely what you are going to do with the time. If you are just going to display it, a `text` field is perfectly fine. If you are going to convert it do different formats, a `long` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else is saying, it all depends on what you want to do with it.

Considering your situation, I would store it in whatever format the server you are going to send it to needs.

As the saying goes, there are many ways to skin this particular cat.  For example: in some instances I've taken the date and converted it to an int in the format of yyyymmdd, that way I can do simple less than/greater than/equal to comparisons without having to resort to the different time functions in SQL.